# Jersey: REST API and two different XML inputs

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am facing the following problem, I have a implemented the following resource in my REST API using Jersey:

```
@POST
@Path("post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String postMethod(final Point point) {
    // do something
}
```

Point corresponds to a XML whose root node is called "point". Now I would like to have a different input, using an XML which a different root node called "encodedPoint". I.e., I would like to discriminate according to posted XML root node.

Is it possible to map the two different XML inputs to only one class? I.e., in the handler for this call, it would be checked that either encodedPoint or point data member is null. Also using two different classes could be OK, but I am not sure if this is compatible with Jersey.

Of course the obvious solution would be to wrap the two elements with a common root node, but I cannot do this due to compatibility reasons with current customers. Obviously what I exposed here is a simplification of the real problem.

Comment: Show us your `Point` class and the JAXB annotations you use on it.

Comment: How about having String as argument, and write your own explicit mapper method, from String to Point, which would perform input detection? (still use JAXB or sth, but for example with simple regexp before that)

Answer (score 0):

No there's no way to have two end points with the same signature (what I call signature here is the combination: (url, method, content-type) )

solution 1: 2 end points using the Path

solution 2: get an entity composed of 2 potionnal attributes Point and encodedPoint and detect which one is present in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found a solution. As easy as replacing the definition of the resource with this:

```
@POST
@Path("post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String postMethod(final JAXBElement<Point> point) {
    // do something
}
```

In this case the two different XMLs (i.e., with different root nodes) will be unmarshaled to a JAXBElement).